# Trying to display youtube video in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to display youtube video in jupyter notebook. But when i place the code in a condition, it doesn't show. But if i remove the if condition it works.

```
from IPython.display import HTML
a = input()
if a=="a":
  HTML('<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/S_f2qV2_U00?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
else:
  print('erro')
```

the code above will not show the box of the video. but if i remove the if condition like in
this one,

```
from IPython.display import HTML
a = input()
HTML('<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/S_f2qV2_U00?    rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" width="560" height="315"  frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
```

it will work just fine.

Comment: Well, are you being prompted for input, what are you typing? The YouTube video is not the problem. You can just put a print statement

Comment: the problem is that if i put the code for the video in a if it will not show the box of the video but if put it without the if it will show

Comment: Simply because your if condition is not working, I assume

Comment: try a if of `"a" == "a"` or something similar, if it works now, use the link above of @cricket_007

Answer (score 26):

Try this trick and let me know:

```
from IPython.display import YouTubeVideo

YouTubeVideo('WSbgixdC9g8', width=800, height=300)
```

Comment: Can we get other information also using this? Note : I don't want to use aditional scrapers.